# How to apply CSS in CartoDB Map layer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cartodb

I am creating one application in which i am using `CartoDB` library for creating layer on map as like creating multi polygon on map.

I created the polygon as well and working fine but its all are in red color.

But i want to apply `css` file for that `CartoDB` Map layer for multiple color theme. So any body having any idea for applying this css in map layer?

I am drawing polygon by calling `CartoDB API` and its `SQLQuery`.

I am calling below api by using `NSURLSession`.

```
NSString *fullUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://test.carto.com/api/v2/sql?q=%@&format=GeoJSON&api_key=60a3b14b8d005c59016a3fc25f11",encodeQuery];
```

So any idea for passing CSS with url or any else way to access CSS file?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you add more detail on what are you using to render those features you are retrieving using the SQL API? Only because of the tags it's implied you are working on iOS development but only with that is hard to know how are you trying to render your map.

Comment: @JorgeSanz Thank you for reply.  i had tried all which is given here : http://mousebird.github.io/WhirlyGlobe/tutorial/ios/cartodb_layer.html

Comment: You probably need then to keep looking on how that library works with vector data. I don't have any experience with it but this looks like a good starting point http://mousebird.github.io/WhirlyGlobe/tutorial/ios/adding_vector_data.html

Answer (score 0):

About the same dataset you can create two layers with different style from a given parameter structure_count.

```
 sublayers: [{
    sql: "SELECT * FROM base_polygon",
    cartocss: '#base_polygon{polygon-opacity: 1;line-color: #FFF;line-width: 1;line-opacity: 1;}#base_polygon[structure_count <= 8000] {polygon-fill: #a50f15;}#base_polygon[structure_count <= 5000] ...'
    },
    sql: "SELECT * FROM base_polygon",
    cartocss: // other style
    }]
```